# kill a java process in Linux

Tags: java, linux

I have a BI application (looker) runs on a linux VM.
tobe able to restart the service, I need to clear the existing java process.
In below screenshot, after run below script, there is a java process, but not showing in the list when I run jps script. What's the reason? and how can I properly terminate this java process?

```
ps aux | grep java
```

[image: screenshot from SSH]

Comment: The process you see by executing `ps aux | grep java` is the `ps`-process...

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried these ?

```
killall java
```

or

```
kill $(pidof java)
```

Comment: Thanks for your comments, I used script "killall java", the console returns "java: no process found", but if I run ps aux | grep java, I can still see this JAVA process, like the screenshot. Any suggestions on how to eventually terminate this java process?

Answer (score 1):

As you can see from your image, the process id is changing each time 9287 / 9304  and represents `| grep java` - and not a java VM!

A common fix is to filter the `ps` results for not matching `| grep -v`,  such as:

```
ps aux | grep java | grep -v --regexp=grep.\*java
```

If there are results above you could append commands to read the process ids and kill command:

```
kill -TERM $(ps aux | grep java | grep -v --regexp=grep.\*java | awk '{print $2}')
```

Note: the above will kill all processes with "java" in name so is not very useful if there are multiple java services for same account. You may need to add filter for specific Java VMs.

Comment: thanks for your comments, good to know this is a process instead of a JAVA VM. How can i eventually terminate this process?